# Why wouldn't Android applications compile from source?

Tags: android

I am trying to compile the default projects that come with Android; however, it doesn't seem to be working at all. Most of the classes and libs seem to be missing.

Comment: Have you downloaded the proper SDK & integrated into Eclipse? The samples bundled with the SDK will compile properly, it's just a matter of your setup. More details?

Answer (score 1):

Did you move your SDK after creating the project? If you did, this breaks the build scripts.

On a secondary note- Google recommends using Eclipse IDE (
 http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1
) for Android Development. Textmate is great, but Eclipse will make your life a lot easier for Android development.

Comment: No, I haven't moved my SDK. The problems is that every other kind of project gets compiled seamlessly; but, when it comes to Android projects(I mean the pre-built projects), it never get compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'm curious. Did you ever try running

```
android update project --path .
```

in the project's directory? I have needed to use that command in the past.